# Transpose multiple rows with one single column

Tags: r, transpose

I have the following data frame:

```
a<-c(2,1,3,6,7)
b<-c(3,1,4,5,8)
c<-c(9,2,5,4,7)



d<- data.frame(a,b,c)
      a b c
    1 2 3 9
    2 1 1 2
    3 3 4 5
    4 6 5 4
    5 7 8 7
```

And I would like to transpose the five rows with one single column, like this:

```
2
3
9
1
1
2
3
4
5
6
5
4
7
8
7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
matrix(t(d),ncol=1)
```

Transpose data.frame and redefine as matrix with 1 column.

Thanks to @DavidArenburg, we can also do:

```
c(t(d))
```

Comment: I'll put this here as I'm not sure what they want `c(t(d))`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume there is a 2-D array that needs to be operated upon in the manner you mentioned. Lets call the array sample[rows][cols], where rows and cols are the sizes of well, rows and columns. I shall give a sample code of the function in C++ that will return the final column vector, as in, it will be an array which you basically can use as the column vector that you required.

```
    int ret_col(int sample[][])
    {
           int i,j,k=0;
           int final_column[rows*cols];

           for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
           {
               for(j=0;j<rows;j++)
               {
                   final_column[k++]=a[j][i];
               }
           }

           return final_column;
    }
```

If there is anything that was not clear in my code, please feel free to ask. Hope this helped! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with the language and I was hoping you will apply the logic I presented in C++ into R. From my experience, its not the language that matters, but the algorithm. Anyhow, sorry for not paying attention to the question.

Comment: Agree with logic, there is also [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) package, which can be used to wrap C code inside R.